# Javascript text change when HTML, PHP code is still running

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was trying to do something similar with multithreading in Java, using PHP. I know that Javascript is single-threaded, PHP doesn't have that much threading as well. This is my code:

```
<body>
  <p id='logS'></p>


  <script>
    function writeMsg(msg) {
      document.getElementById("logS").innerHTML += msg;
    }

    setInterval(function(){ // this function is for testing
      document.getElementById("logS").innerHTML += "-Boop-<br/>";
    },500);
  </script>

  <?php
    $arrayTest = array(); 
    // Add elements into array
    $myVariables = 0; // some value

    for($i=0;$i<count($arrayTest);$i++){
      runProcess($myVariables);

      echo "<script>";
      echo "writeMsg('Counter '".$i."' is completed.<br/>')";
      echo "</script>";
    }

    function runProcess($variables){
      // my complicated codes (1 second to complete)
    }
  ?>
</body>
```

Assuming my $arrayTest has 2 elements, and each runProcess will take about 1 seconds to load (due to looping, sql_queries)

What I hope to achieve for 'logS' is this format:

-Boop-
-Boop-
Counter 0 is completed.
-Boop-
-Boop-
Counter 1 is completed.
-Boop-
-Boop- (Infinitely echo '-Boop-' each 0.5seconds)

And what I got is the page runs for 2 seconds not Booping (for the runProcess()) code, then only -Boop-s.

Counter 0 is completed.
Counter 1 is completed.
-Boop-
-Boop- (Infinitely echo '-Boop-' each 0.5seconds)

So let's say a 1000 elements in array, meaning that it will run for 1000 seconds without echoing stuff, then after that print the whole "Counter x is completed" then only start Booping, which defeats the purpose for my code.

To summarise:

What I wanted to do is have each counter completed, it will show that it is completed. Like a log.

Is it even possible to do such in HTML,PHP and Javascript? Thanks!

Comment: are you running this with an empty array `count($arrayTest);`

Comment: you may find this interesting https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I did write a comment called // Add elements into array so I don't need to show the complicated codings for the array. Thanks for the reference as well.

Comment: I was meaning that if the input array for the `for` loop is empty this code wont do anything.  Also I wouldn't ask for the complicated "things" but it would be helpful to have some sample data to test the code against.

Comment: One last thing Is I don't know if you are confusing "multithreading" with "asynchronous"  PHP doesn't really have an issue with either, more the issue is with apache and the nature of the HTTP protocol ( request -> response ).

Comment: I've developed and maintain a multi-threaded/horizontal search application,  that uses PHP, MySql, MongoDB, Sphinx Searchd, RabbitMq.  It runs on 2 servers ( right now ) searches about 180 Million rows/searches a day, and can run nearly 200k csv lines through in one Minute, literally.  ( For example )  it can also send and receive files over sSftp, :-)  One server has 12 cores and 56G memory, the other is a dual core with only 8G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the flush function in php.

```
  echo "<script>";
  echo "writeMsg('Counter '".$i."' is completed.<br/>')";
  echo "</script>";

  ob_flush();
  flush();
```

Comment: It works! I wrote this much, and you just simply answered it. Thank you!